# Comment out / uncomment source blocks on state change in org-mode config file

Tags: org-mode, comment, todo

I started to move my config file to an org-file just recently.

I wondered if it was possible to use the TODO state to activate or deactivate source blocks in the entry under the heading. This way it would be very easy to try out settings and customization.

Example: with `#+TODO: ON | OFF`

```
* ON use org-bullets
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   (require 'org-bullets)
   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
  #+END_SRC
```

and after state change it would be

```
* OFF use org-bullets
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   ;;(require 'org-bullets)
   ;;(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
  #+END_SRC
```

I thought about using the `org-after-todo-state-change-hook` but I know too litte elisp to go beyond that. The setting should only work in the config.org file, not in other org files.

Any helpful idea is appreciated.

P.S.: my `M-x emacs-version` is

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, GTK+ Version 3.24.5) of 2019-09-23, modified by Debian
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the todo state to the special keyword `COMMENT` the entire heading will be treated as a comment and no source blocks under it will run.

Comment: Thank you! This solves it. I found `C-c ; (org-toggle-comment)` to be very handy.